# remote connection to sql database

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2005

What is the connection string which connect remotely to sql database via visual studio c. Net

Comment: Please help me, my English not so good

Comment: Sql server 2005, no security

Comment: When I excute my program, give me no connection

Answer (score 0):

open ***ServerExplorer*** in ***ViEW*** menue then Right Click On Your DataBase go to *Property* there is a *ConnectionString* htat is what u want

Comment: if there is no DataBase in  ServerExplorer ,right click on DataConnections  go to Add Connections>Microsoft Sql Server>then choose your Server Name then Your DataBase Name>OK..